# function with array with pointer as parameter

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, structure, function-pointers

Context: We are in a library. We wrote two structures: Livre (book in english) with titre (title), nombre_pages (number of pages) and statut (borrowed already or not? )

Lecteur (the reader) (nom = name; prenom = firstname; nb_livres = number of books the reader has booked already; and a struct livres)

I'm trying to do a function in which the parameters are:
1) Array with different readers (structure Lecteur)
2) The size of the array (with a pointer because it will evolve)
3) The reader (structure Lecteur) that has to be delete of the array.

Here is my function:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

struct Livre {
    char titre[100];
    int nombre_pages;
    int statut; // Book already borrowed = 1, Available = 0
};

struct Lecteur {
    char nom[100];
    char prenom[100];
    int nb_livres; // le nombre de livres dans le tableau "livres"
    struct Livre* livres[100]; // livres deja empruntes (eventuellement rendus)

};

void desabonnement(struct Lecteur * plecteurs[], int * nombre_lecteurs,
  struct Lecteur * lect) {

  struct Lecteur empty = {  // Cette variable me permettra de transformer la valeur qui m'intérésse pas
    0
  };
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;

  while ((plecteurs[i]->nom != lect->nom) &&
    (plecteurs[i]->prenom != lect->prenom)) {
    i++;
  }
  while (j < plecteurs[i]->nb_livres) {
    plecteurs[i]->livres[j]->statut = 0;
    j++;
  }
  while (i < * nombre_lecteurs) {
    *plecteurs[i] = *plecteurs[i + 1];
    i++;
  }

  *plecteurs[i] = empty;

}



int main() {

    struct Livre l1 = { "boom" , 50 , 1 };
    struct Livre l2 = { "bim" , 50 , 1 };
    struct Livre l3 = { "chaud" , 50 , 0 };
    struct Livre l4 = { "tcho" , 50 , 1 };
    struct Livre l5 = { "braa" , 50 , 1 };

    struct Livre *p1 = & l1;
    struct Livre *p2 = & l2;
    struct Livre *p3 = & l3;
    struct Livre *p4 = & l4;
    struct Livre *p5 = & l5;





    struct Lecteur le1 = { "Boso" , "Nen" , 2 , {&l1, &l2} };;
    struct Lecteur le2 = { "Jogar" , "Elo" , 1 , {&l3} };;
    struct Lecteur le3 = { "marche" , "silteplait" , 2 , {&l4, &l5} };;


    struct Lecteur *tableau_test[3] = {&le1, &le2, &le3};
    int le_nombre = 3;


    desabonnement(tableau_test, &le_nombre, &le3);


        printf(" %d ", tableau_test[0]->nb_livres);




    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it? What happened when you ran it through your debugger?

Comment: I tried to write in the main stuff to try the function but, even if i didnt get error or warning, nothing happened. I will post my main in the former message.

Comment: The code you posted does not even compile. Please [edit] your question and post a [mcve]

Comment: When I copied it, some arrows were like this: - > and not like this -> , which makes errors. Sorry!! I changed it and it compile well!!

Comment: In following line  the array index `i + 1` goes out of bounds:

   `*plecteurs[i] = *plecteurs[i + 1];`

You could have found out this yourself by using your debugger.

BTW: the overall design of your program is very poor.

Comment: Thanks !! What do you mean by that? Why is it very poor?

Comment: Bad design... For example: `*plecteurs[i] = empty;` is a bad choice, `plecteurs[i]=NULL` is preferable.

Comment: I ve got an error when I try to put NULL ... I would prefer an other option, but I didn't find one

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in line `while (i < * nombre_lecteurs)` of function `void desabonnement(struct Lecteur * plecteurs[], int * nombre_lecteurs, struct Lecteur * lect)`. This should be `while (i+1 < * nombre_lecteurs)`.

See complete working code [here](https://ideone.com/C20if7).

**Note:** In your actual code, You should decrease the `le_nombre` when deletion is complete to reflect the new size (I have done this in the [corrected code here](https://ideone.com/C20if7)).

Answer (score 0):

Actually what is your question?

Just some remarks:

First I'd consider `(plecteurs[i]->nom != lect->nom)` a shorthand for 
`strcmp(plecteurs[i]->nom, lect->nom) != 0`. Same applies to `prenom`.
You should correct this.

The snippet

```
while (j < plecteurs[i]->nb_livres) {
    plecteurs[i]->livres[j]->statut = 0;
    j++;
}
```

makes the books available without returning them. To me this seems unlogical, 
because the reader may not have given back the book. But this may be 
conforming with the (homework?) assignment you are working at.
Note that the array of books may have holes your code ignores.
Are all books packed to the beginning of the array when a book is returned?
In other word, is

```
struct Lecteur le4 = { "murche" , "silmeplait" , 2 , {&l4, 0, &l5} };
```

invalid?

I didn't test your function but a first superficial look seems that it should 
compile and with the `strcmp()` - correction it sould run as you expect.
(Your null-lector is invalid, learn the use of `NULL` pointers).

Besides: Why do you use a double semicolon `;;`?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your remarks! For the semicolon, its a mistake, I didnt see it !! For the rest, as you said, its a homework with some particular specifications!!